# uibarbuttonitem tintColor

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uitoolbar

I have 2 buttons on a UIToolbar, I'd like one to be tinted green and the other red. Can I do this using the TintColor feature. Or do I have to use images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I misread. If you want to tint the buttons individually, your only option is going to be images and custom views.

I would warn you though, this is a blatant violation of the HIG. I don't think it'll be liked by the review team.

Comment: Well one is a confirm button, the other is a definitely not confirmed button. It makes sense to one green and one red, or at least one of them red and the other normal.

Comment: I had an app in the past with a button with different color. They never said anything about HIG violation ;)